# async* blocking function body from executing

Tags: dart

When adding async* to listen method it isn't executing the function body

```
import 'dart:async';

main(List<String> args) {
  print('====');
  tranStream();
}

Stream<int> intStreamer() async* {
  int c = 0;
  while (c <= 30) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield c++;
  }
}

tranStream() {
  intStreamer().listen((event) async* { // If i remove async* from here it will execute print statement
    print(event);
  });
}
```

If i remove async* from `intStreamer().listen` it will execute print statement. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `async*`, the method will only start being executed when the returned `Stream` gets a subscriber. Your code does not really make any sense since `listen` takes a method which returns `void`. So nobody are going to listen on the returned `Stream` which the given method will automatically return (based on the `async*` keyword).

I would also properly rewrite your code so you instead of `listen` uses `await for` which I think makes it more clear what happens`:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  print('====');
  await tranStream();
}

Stream<int> intStreamer() async* {
  int c = 0;
  while (c <= 30) {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield c++;
  }
}

Future<void> tranStream() async {
  await for (final event in intStreamer()) {
    print(event);
  }
}
```

Update with example of `tranStream` returns a Stream:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  print('====');
  await for (final event in tranStream()) {
    print('main got: $event');
  }
}

Stream<int> intStreamer() async* {
  int c = 0;
  while (c <= 30) {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield c++;
  }
}

Stream<int> tranStream() async* {
  await for (final event in intStreamer()) {
    print('tranStream got: $event');
    yield event;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay. but what  if I want tranStream() returns a stream from intStreamer() by listening to it. How do I yield from listen's callback with async*

Comment: Using my `await for` solution should make it easy enough? You can just mark `tranStream` as `async*`, return a `Stream` and use `yield` as you would normally do? I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Yes, That'll work. Thanks for your help. 1 more doubt what if intStreamer() isn't asynchronous generator but a StreamController which will emit events randomly, so does await for will works here similarly

Comment: @arunized It does not really change anything. You can still subscribe to the returned `Stream` and do what you want. I can recommend read more about Streams in the language tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#handling-streams